# What is the difference between :encoding(utf8) and :utf8?

Tags: perl, encoding, utf-8

Given the two,

```
use open ':utf8';
use open ':encoding(utf8)';
```

What is the difference? Likewise, between

```
binmode *STDOUT, ':utf8';
binmode *STDOUT, ':encoding(utf8)';
```

Comment: @Grinnz yep, i marked it as a dupe after i found it.